# Implement chain() for a GATified Lending Iterator

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement an `Iterator::chain()`-like operation for a GATified lending iterator:

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

pub trait LendingIterator {
    type Item<'a> where Self: 'a;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'_>>;
}
```

To do this, similarly to the normal Iterator::chain(), I need a struct `Chain` that contains the two chained iterators and impl's `LendingIterator`.

The problem I have is I need to specify the iterator types `A` and `B` having matching `Item` generic associated types, so I tried this:

```rust
pub struct Chain<A, B> {
    a: Option<A>,
    b: Option<B>,
}

impl<A, B> LendingIterator for Chain<A, B>
    where
        A: LendingIterator,
        B: for<'a> LendingIterator<Item<'a>=A::Item<'a>>
{
    type Item<'a> where Self: 'a = A::Item<'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'_>> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

But I get:

```
error[E0311]: the parameter type `B` may not live long enough
  --> src\lib.rs:63:12
   |
63 | impl<A, B> LendingIterator for Chain<A, B> where A: LendingIterator, B: for<'a> LendingIterator<Item<'a>=A::Item<'a>> {
   |         -  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `B` will meet its required lifetime bounds...
   |         |
   |         help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `B: 'a`
   |
note: ...that is required by this bound
   |        ^^^^ ...so that the type `B` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

Of course the compiler's suggestions don't seem to work.

How can I add the constraint that `B` does have a long enough lifetime?

Comment: Nitpick: you can do `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'_>>;`

Comment: Lifetime `'b` is undefined - did you mean `'a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in rust's GAT implementation. See this:

https://rust-lang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/122651-general/topic/.E2.9C.94.20GAT.20LendingIterator.3A.3Achain.20Issue

https://rust-lang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/213817-t-lang/topic/Understanding.20the.20motivations.20for.20GATs/near/269863728